# Is clang a standalone C compiler or does it need gcc?

Tags: c, windows, clang

I want to use clang on Windows to compile C code.

I'd like to know if it is in fact a standalone compiler that can do that, or are its aims somewhat different?

I've used it before, but it appears now that is was piggy-backing on top of whatever gcc compilers were lying around (mingw for example).

If I try a fresh binary installation of clang 64-bits (and I hide my mingw/gcc directories), then it can't find stdio.h for Hello World. This is running from directly inside the bin directory (C:\clang\bin). If I unhide mingw, it will compile, but then I get errors like this (one mingw compiler is in c:\win):

c:\win\bin\ld.exe cannot find -lgcc_s

Considering clang is a 438MB installation, you'd think it would have it's own include and library files! I want to use clang *in place* of gcc.

So, what am I doing wrong? (I've seen a few questions also about the inability to find stdio.h, but they weren't helpful. Surely clang must be able to compile Hello World by itself?!)

Comment: That's ... blatantly false. FreeBSD uses Clang entirely and doesn't use GCC at all (nor does it install GCC anymore).

Comment: Neither Clang nor GCC contain a C library. However you deploy either, there'll be a separate C library somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing compiler with linker with standard library.

Clang is a full featured independent compiler. But it does not provides the standard library (the library containing `stdio.h`). Traditionally, on Unix systems, the operating systems must provide the standard library it uses. But since you are using Windows, it doesn't, and for whatever reason it finds the ones from MingW installed. There are many free implementations of C standard library which are compatible with Clang.

Lastly, `ld.exe` is the linker, and it also, traditionally, must be provided by the system. There is one linker, [lld](http://lld.llvm.org/), that I believe is being developed alongside Clang, but for whatever reason, the packager of the version you downloaded just chose to configure clang to simply call `ld`.

Comment: I've used other C compilers such as DMC, Pelles C, lccwin, and TinyCC as well as gcc. They all come with their own headers, own linkers, and own library files. Are you saying clang does not fit that pattern (despite its massive size compared with most of those)? There is a lld program, but it's rather bizarre, and doesn't even recognise the hello.o file created by clang!

Comment: Yes. It doesn't fit that Windows ready-to-use bundle pattern. And Gcc doesn't fit in the pattern of the compilers you mentioned, either. MingW (which contains a build of GCC) might, but not GCC. It doesn't even have an official binary distribution.

Comment: By the way, Digital Mars product is called "C and C++ Development System", and contains much more than a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Clang is a completely separate compiler (written entirely from scratch, using LLVM). You don't need GCC to use Clang, as can be shown in the case of FreeBSD (they completely replaced GCC with Clang/LLVM and don't install GCC in the base anymore for licensing reasons). There are a variety of different C compilers other than GCC, it's just that GCC is the most common.

However, no compiler provides the standard C libraries (GCC provides some weird libraries like the one you're trying to use). C libraries are provided separately, and you need to install C libraries in order to compile any significant C program. The error message saying `cannot find -lgcc_s` tells me that you're trying to link against some library provided by GCC. In this case, you probably want to install that library by installing GCC (but note that you don't **need** GCC to use Clang.

It does appear that your version of Clang has been compiled to use GNU's linked `ld`, not LLVM's linked `lld`. As such, you'll need GCC's linker (or you can recompile clang to use LLVM's linker, or just compile the object files and use `lld` separately).

Comment: Are you sure that the default linker dependency is **compiled** into the compiler binary? This sounds like an insanely useless choice to me.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are missing a path variable. After install you must manually add a PATH to the Windows Environment.

Comment: PATH specifies a search path for executables. The OP is able to invoke the compiler, but the compiler can't find `stdio.h`. PATH has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Any Program can call the PATH

Comment: I did not say he should add to the PATH. He is missing a PATH Variable.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The `%PATH%` (Windows) or `$PATH` (Unix/Linux) variable specifies how to find executables such as gcc or clang. The OP says he is already able to execute clang. The problem was that clang couldn't find `stdio.h`. That's not controlled by `%PATH%`/`$PATH`. There is a search path for include files but it's not called "PATH". If you have a solution, you'll need to be much more specific. With a properly configured system, it shouldn't be necessary to add anything explicitly.

Comment: If you do not install clang as Administrator you have to add some variables to the Environemt manually.

Comment: Is PATH one of those variables? Your answer might be useful with more details. What variables need to be set, and to what values? clang itself doesn't provide `stdio.h`. Some package might include both clang and the library.